# linux chmod all leading directories

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

Do we have a way to 'chmod' all leading directories in linux?

For example,

when the permission of 'flex' directory in the path '/local_home/my_home/flex/source' is set to 000,

chmod 755 /local_home/my_home/flex/source/ will fail due to the permission of 'flex' directory.

I want to change all permissions of directories presented in the second parameter of 'chmod' command.

Do we have the solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the chmod command as root user or as a sudoer (sudo chmod ...) otherwise it fails. If you use:

```
sudo chmod 755 /path/to/flex
```

the permission reflects only on the 'flex' directory. If you want to set the permission to all of his (flex) child files and directories you should use the '-R' option, which stands for recursively. In this case your command will like this:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/flex
```